# Cannot get past the login screen after upgading

Tags: 12.04, command-line

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04. After logging in I get the following message:

```
keith@keith-desktop:~$
```

Where do I go from here?

I have tried most commands I have found on forum pages but nothing seems to work. It keeps arriving back at the message.

I'm at a total loss and quite new to Ubuntu programming!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you upgraded **to** or **from** Ubuntu 12.04? Also, are you using Ubuntu desktop or server?

Comment: What commands are those "most commands I have found on forum pages" ? Please provide the eroors(if any) provided by these commands

Comment: Try `startx` in console to run desktop environment. You need to configure display manager. For example `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`